# Reported Questions

Tags: tenses, indirect-speech

I have a question about the use of reported speech.

" Who were with you", asked Tom.

If I have to change the above question into a reported question, should the answer be

1. Tom asked me who I had been with. Or
2. Tom asked me who had been with me.

Thanks!

Comment: This hinges on knowing the distinction between _who were you with_ and _who were with you_, although they essentially mean the same thing.

Comment: I don't think "Who were with you" is even grammatically correct, it's plural. It should either be "who were you with" or "who was with you" - though this is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @turkey 'Who' can take a plural verb; here, the implication is that the questioner is aware that there were more than 2 people present. 'Who were [those men] with you?' // But yes, 'Who was with you?' does sound more natural and does not entail that [the questioner knows that] there were only 2 people present.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are grammatically correct, and have essentially the same meaning, with a slight difference in emphasis: "... who I had been with" emphasises the active participation of the speaker, where "... who had been with me" emphasises the active participation of the others.

"... who had been with me." is the most direct paraphrase of the direct question "Who were with you?". The direct equivalent of "... who had been with me" would be "Who were you with?"

Comment: There **_is_** a sense where only one answer works. "I know that when you said this, some of the people on the board disagreed strongly. Who were with you?" shows a non-reciprocal case.